# Laplace equation conducting sphere

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to solve the Laplace equation for a conducting sphere of radius $r$ and potential $V0$.

I impose that on the surface the potential is $V0$ and that at long distance from the center the potential is null.

The exact solution is known so I can verify my result, and what I obtain is wrong.

This is my simple code:

```
    r = 1.5;
    V0 = 0.6;
    lim = 100 r;
    Domain = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, lim], Disk[{0, 0}, r]];
    sol1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
                         DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V0, x^2 + y^2 == r^2], 
                         DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 >= lim^2]}, 
           u, {x, y} ∈ Domain];
    Plot[{V0 r/Sqrt[x^2], sol1[x, 0]}, {x, -2, 8}]
```

I don't understand where i'm wrong.

My ultimate goal is to work with three spheres, but if I can not even with one ...

Comment: Are you sure the "exact solution" is correct? Try `D[V0 r/Sqrt[x^2], x, x] + D[V0 r/Sqrt[x^2], y, y]`.

Comment: Also, you are solving the DE numerically in the annulus $r^2 < x^2 + y^2 < lim^2$, so you should not expect the plot to be meaningful for $|x| < r$ when $y=0$.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the solution must be the potential of a conducting sphere $\sim 1/|r|$ and i'm checking the solution for $|x|>r$. Where i'm wrong?

Comment: No you were checking it for $-2 < x < 8$ and $y=0$, that includes the origin $r=0$. Or did you mean to plot $2 < x < 8$?

Comment: Yes you're right in the code i plot the solution for $-2<x<8$ but only for convenience.

Comment: The solution is not the same for a Disk (2D problem) and for a Sphere (3D problem). For the sphere V(r) is proportional to 1/r, for the Disk to Log[r]

Comment: Ok, but the solution of NDSolve is not Log[r].

Comment: Yes it is! Writing the solution as `u[x, 0] = a(Log[x] + b)` and solving for the boundary conditions gives `u[x, 0] = V0(Log[x] - Log[lim])/(Log[r] - Log[lim])`, which you can see agrees very well with the `NDSolve` curve by plotting it. Try `Plot[{V0/(Log[r] - Log[lim]) (Log[x] - Log[lim]), 
  sol1[x, 0]}, {x, r, lim}, PlotRange -> {{r, lim}, {0, V0}}]`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As requested in a comment, an answer:

In a **2D** system with rotational invariance, the Laplace equation in polar coordinates is

$$ \nabla^2 u(r,\theta) = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 0$$
Notice the $1/r$ here, which would have been a $2/r$ in the 3D case. The equation is separable, so introducing $v = \partial u / \partial r$ gives

$$ \frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} = - \frac{1}{r} $$
with solution $$v = \frac{a}{r} $$ and thus $$u(r) = a(\ln r + b)$$
The boundary conditions $u(r') = V_0$, $u(L) = 0$ give

$$ u(r) = \frac{V_0(\ln r - \ln L)}{\ln r' - \ln L}$$

Now, the solution from `NDSolve` is demonstrably very good:

```
r = 1.5;
V0 = 0.6;
lim = 100 r;

formula = V0(Log[x] - Log[lim])/(Log[r] - Log[lim]);

Domain = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, lim], Disk[{0, 0}, r]];
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
                     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V0, x^2 + y^2 == r^2], 
                     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 >= lim^2]}, 
       u, {x, y} ∈ Domain];
Plot[{formula, sol1[x, 0]}, {x, r, lim}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Abs[formula - sol1[x, 0]], {x, r, lim}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]